# Firebase messaging notification message vs data message and different behavior on ios/android

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When i send a notification message, under android i can not set the largeIcon, so i must use data message and construct myself the notification inside the notification service who listen incoming data message.

However, on IOS, their is no such "notification service" running in background and the app will receive the data message only when it's become foreground (as far as i understand). so it's seam on ios the only choice i have is to send notification message with are incompatible with android

Is their something i miss ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, your description is right.

we are working on making the API more flexible, both on the server side and on the client side.

Unfortunately we don't have anything to announce at this time.